# Nginx root directory

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm new to Nginx and I'm in the process of setting it up but one thing that I don't understand is the root path. How is it different than Apache?

Right now I have Apache and my files are all /home/servername/public_html/

So under Nginx, would the root path be the same? All the tutorials for migrating from Apache to Nginx I see they show the default like /user/share/nginx/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. This is the location of files for your website.

**This is quite good comparison:**

```
Apache                                 Nginx
------                                 ------

<VirtualHost *:80>                     server {
                                            listen 80;

ServerName yoursite.com
ServerAlias www.yoursite.com           server_name yoursite.com www.yoursite.com;

DocumentRoot /path/to/root             root /path/to/root;

AllowOverride All                      (No Available Alternative)

DirectoryIndex index.php               index index.php;

ErrorLog /path/to/log                  error_log /path/to/log error;

CustomLog /path/to/log combined        access_log /path/to/log main;

Alias /url/ "/path/to/files"           location /url/ {
<Directory "/path/to/files">                 alias /path/to/files;
```

Found on [DigitalOcean ;)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

Comment: Ah ok, got it. Thanks for the response.